# Convert query result to HTML list

Tags: php, mysql

I'm really just dipping my toes into the PHP and MySQL waters.  I've made this work the way I want it to, but I know it's ugly and I'd like to know how it would be done by someone who actually knows what they're doing.

```
    function displayCategoryMenu($db){  
       echo '<ul class="class">';
       foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM categoryDb, thingDb WHERE category = category AND categoryId= "aaa0001"  ORDER BY category, thingName') as $row){
          if($categoryName!== $row['categoryName']){
            $categoryName= $row['CategoryName'];
            echo '<li class="category">'.$categoryName.'</li>';
          }
          echo'<li><a class="fader" href="?&amp;page='.$row['thingId']">'.$row['thingName'].'</a></li>';
      }
      echo '</ul>';

       echo '<ul class="class">';
       foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM categoryDb, thingDb WHERE category = category AND categoryId= "aaa0002"  ORDER BY category, thingName') as $row){
          if($categoryName!== $row['categoryName']){
            $categoryName= $row['CategoryName'];
            echo '<li class="category">'.$categoryName.'</li>';
          }
          echo'<li><a class="fader" href="?&amp;page='.$row['thingId']">'.$row['thingName'].'</a></li>';
      }
      echo '</ul>';
      $db=null;
    }
```

This basically results in an unordered list menu, where the first child acts as a header:

```
    <ul>
       <li>category1Name</li>
       <li><a>thing</a></li>
       <li><a>thing</a></li>
       <li><a>thing</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li>category2Name</li>
       <li><a>thing</a></li>
       <li><a>thing</a></li>
       <li><a>thing</a></li>
    </ul>
```

or:

**Category1**

- Thing
- Thing
- Thing

**Category2**

- Thing
- Thing
- Thing

and so forth...

The only difference in each ul's code is the "categoryId" (aaa0001, aaa0002, etc...)  I can only imagine that I'm going about this the hard way, with the ugliest code that I can muster.  I'd love to see how it should be done.

Comment: Well done on the question.  Up vote, plus some proposed edits.  I dropped two tags as less-relevant and revised the title to "Convert query result to HTML list" (you may not see that change right away, it must be peer-reviewed; or you can revise it yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the list of category ids somewhere in an array, an iterate over that while using a variable in place of the category ID. Something like :

```
function displayCategoryMenu($db){  
    $categoryIds = array('aaa0001', 'aaa0002');

    foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
        echo '<ul class="class">';
        foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM categoryDb, thingDb WHERE category = category AND categoryId= "' . $categoryId . '"  ORDER BY category, thingName') as $row) {
            if($categoryName !== $row['categoryName']){
                $categoryName = $row['CategoryName'];
                echo '<li class="category">' . $categoryName . '</li>';
            }
            echo '<li><a class="fader" href="?&amp;page=' . $row['thingId'] . '">' . $row['thingName'] . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Here the array `$categoryIds` contain the list of IDs you have to display, you can generate it dynamically or pass it as a function parameter as you wish, it's easily expandable. The `foreach` loop iterate over each element of this array and do exactly the same the HTML display and SQL query job for each of the ID denoted by the `$categoryId` variable in the loop.

**Sidenote** about your `$db = null;` line : if you don't pass the `$db` function parameter [as a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), modifying its *value* in your function the way yo did it will not have any influence on the original variable, this line is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same functions you did, I would select all the categories and things at the same time, like so:

```
function renderCategoryMenus($db, $category_id_array)
{  
   // Convery array('a00','b00') to string "'a00','b00'"
   $category_ids = "'" . implode("','", $category_id_array) "'";

   // Change * to just the fields you need
   // Use a join
   // WHERE id IN ('a00','b00')

   $query = 
      'SELECT CategoryName, thingName 
      FROM categoryDb 
      INNER JOIN thingDb 
      ON categoryDb.category = thingDb.category 
      WHERE categoryId IN \''. $category_ids .'\'  
      ORDER BY category, thingName'; 

   $results = $db->query($query);

   // Initialize your variables
   $output = '';
   $categoryName = '';

   foreach($results as $row) 
   {
      if ($categoryName != $row['categoryName']) // If this is a new category
      {
         if ($categoryName != '') // And it is NOT the first new category
         {
            $output .= '</ul>'; // End off the previous category
         }         

         $categoryName = $row['CategoryName'];

         // Store your output into a variable so you can return it
         $output .= '<ul class="class"><li class="category">' . 
            $categoryName . '</li>';
      }

      $output .= '<li><a class="fader" href="?&amp;page=' . 
         $row['thingId'] . '>' . $row['thingName'] . '</a></li>';
   }

   // End off the last category
   if ($output != '') // If we had any categories whatsoever
   {
      $output .= '</ul>';
   }

    return $output;
}    

echo renderCategoryMenus($db, array('aaa0001', 'aaa0002'));
```

A simpler way would be to use an Object Relational Mapper like Yii has.

With [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/), you could do something as simple as this:

```
function renderCategoryAsMenu($category)
{  
   $output .= '<ul class="class"><li class="category">' . 
      $categoryName . '</li>';      

   // This bit actually selects all 'things' in this 'category'
   foreach ($category->things as $thing)   
      $output .= '<li><a class="fader" href="?&amp;page=' . 
         $thing->thingId . '>' . $thing->thingName . '</a></li>';
   }

   $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}    

$category_keys = array('a00','b00');
$categories = Category::model()->findAllByPk($category_keys);

$output = '';
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
   $output .= renderCategoryAsMenu();
}
echo output;
```

You could even make renderCategoryAsMenu a function on the Model, in which case you could just say `$category->renderAsMenu()`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which categoryIDs you wish to show:

I would suggest 1 query and loop through the resultset.

That would be either

1) without the WHERE clausule (unless you need it for the join, still, since you have 2 WHERE conditions)

```
SELECT * FROM categoryDb, thingDb ORDER BY category, thingName
```

2) or expand the WHERE

```
WHERE categoryId="aaa001" OR categoryId="aaa002" ...
```

Also I would suggest:

```
if($categoryName!== $row['categoryName'])
{
    echo '<li class="category">' . $row['CategoryName'] . '</li>';
}
```

You could rename the function to "writeCategoryMenu".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.. i think it's much easier...
and for debugging i'd advice you to use i.e. `$sql_query`:

```
<?php
function displayCategoryMenu($db){  

    $sql_query  =  'SELECT * FROM 
                        categoryDb 
                    LEFT JOIN thingDb
                        ON categoryDb.category = thingDb.category
                    WHERE
                        thingDb.visible = 1                     
                    ORDER BY 
                        thingDb.category ASC, 
                        thingDb.thingName';

    $result = $db->query($sql_query);
    if(!mysql_error()){

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        if($currentcategory <> $row['CategoryName']){
            $output .=  '<ul class="class">';
            $output .=  '   <li class="category">'.$categoryName.'</li>';
            $output .=  '   <li><a class="fader" href="?&amp;page='.$row['thingId'].'">'.$row['thingName'].'</a></li>';
            $output .=  '</ul>';
        } else {
            $output .=  '<li><a class="fader" href="?&amp;page='.$row['thingId'].'">'.$row['thingName'].'</a></li>';
        }

        $currentcategory = $row['CategoryName'];

    }
    }else{
        $output = mysql_error().'<br>QUERY: '.$sql_query;
    }

    echo $output;

?>
```